# Android: current 'x' position on Gallery widget

Tags: android, widget, gallery, horizontalscrollview

I'm wondering how to get current X position on Gallery widget in Android? Is it even possible? `getX()` and `getScrollX()` gives me 0 all the time.

I need to make a 100-elements long horizontal scrolling view with effect like in MacOS dock menu. Maybe you've got some ideas for that?

Comment: Something like that? http://evgeni-shafran.blogspot.com/2011/08/tutorial-custom-gallery-circular-and.html

Comment: Unfortunately it works quite crappy. I made something similar but with Animation to zoomIn.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of

```
yourGallery.getAdapter().getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Which would return which position in the adapter you're currently at.
I'm not 100% sure that this is what you're after as you have tried the `getScroll()` and `getX()` which would return pixel values, but you will find that from getAdapter() you can get access to a lot of methods relating to the underlying data.

Comment: I know this method and actually I'm using it as a extremity - getting current position and multiplying with child width. Yes - I need values in px, every 1px.

Comment: Ok, well, best of luck to you :)